# jquery mobile Panel Swipe function causing errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, initialization, panel, swipe

I'm having such a hard time, I have a flip clock using mootools, then a weather widget using Yahoo API, now I have no idea what is causing

> "cannot call methods on panel prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'open'"

SO i followed this demo, http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/docs/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.php#demo-page and now i'm getting the error.

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {
$( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {
    // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
    // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
    // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
    if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
        if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
            $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
        } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
            $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
        }
    }
});
```

});

I'm sorta at a dead end cause I had it work, feel free to look at my code, http://yaasko.com/gra423/project-4.3/ if you try to swipe left or right the console will output the error.

Please let me know if you can help, first time jquery mobile user!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case of this msg:

> "cannot call methods on panel prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'open'"

open panel like this:

```
$( "#left-panel" ).panel().panel("open");
```

First panel() call will initialize it and second one will open it.

**EDIT :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){        
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#index", function( e ) {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.find('#left-panel').hasClass('ui-panel-closed') && e.type === "swipeleft") {
            $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" ); 
        }    

        if ($.mobile.activePage.find('#right-panel').hasClass('ui-panel-closed') &&  e.type === "swiperight") {
            $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );           
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, here is what I did
    `if ( $j.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
                $j( "#right-panel" ).panel().panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                $j( "#left-panel" ).panel().panel("open");
            }
        }`

now i get _Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined _ and also this _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'jqmData' of null _

Comment: You are a life saver ! puno hvala ja sam iz velka kladusa bosna ali sam doso u ameriku kad sam imo 6 godina, nista vidimo se ZIVI !

Comment: Nema problema, ako budeš trebao dodatnu pomoć javi mi se na mail direktno.