# Have multiple pages with panels that have the same name and need to swipe open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

For example, I have two pages with panels in my doc, the panels have the same names, it looks like this:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
      <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel">...</div>
      <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel">...</div>
      ...
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel">...</div>
      <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel">...</div>
      ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can get the swiping to work for the first page that loads but once i load a new page the swiping breaks giving me this error `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on panel prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'`. I tried the solution outlined [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967382/jquery-mobile-panel-swipe-function-causing-errors) but it didn't work for me. I am using this code to swipe open the panels:

```
 $("#page1").on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
        if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
            $("#right-panel").panel("open");
        } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
            $("#left-panel").panel("open");
        }
    }
});

$("#page2").on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
        if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
            $("#right-panel").panel("open");
        } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
            $("#left-panel").panel("open");
        }
    }
});
```

which is inside `$(document).on("pageinit", function(){... it's at the end of this function});` I thought that because I was binding the swipe listeners to each page it would work out that each page would have swiping capabilities but no such luck.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying? I've tried multiple solutions, like loading just the swipe listener code each time a page is changed, using a class (`.page`) on each page and using one instance of the swipe listener code but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try `'pageinit', '[data-role=page', function()` if it doesn't work remove `pageinit` binding.

Comment: tried both of your suggestions and neither worked

Comment: Wait a minute. Is your html one page? If yes then you have twice the same ids

Comment: Do you have panels in each page? And btw, I had a mistake in my first comment, I forgot `]`. It should be `[data-role=page]`

Comment: @alkis it's okay when targeting active page.

Comment: Your event handlers are fine, but are you sure that the two ids don't mess jqm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out, @alkis you were partially right, the multiple ids were messing with jQuery Mobile, but in addition to differentiating between the panel ids I also had to change my javascript file's binding to `$(document).ready(function(){...});` and then wrap each swipe handler in its own `$("#pagenamehere").on("pageinit", function(){...});` binding. +1 to you @alkis I wouldnt have figured it out if you hadn't mentioned about the multiple ids, I just thought since they were separate pages I could use the same ids and only have one swipe handler, no such luck. Thanks.